# Initialise a variable with a specific date in a specific format

Tags: unix

I want to initialise a variable with yesterday's date in a specific format, eg: 
If today is 15 Feb, then variable should be `var=Feb 14`.

`date -d"-1day" +"%b %d"` is not working, I do not know why.

How do we do it correctly or any other way?

Comment: Which Unix are you using?

Comment: ^^^ What he said

Comment: as others have said, you need to say which UNIX, or more important, which date command you have. The answers given should work for gnu date.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using bash:

```
var=`date -d"-1day" +"%b %d"`
```

You forgot the backticks. More visual:

```
var=$(date -d"-1day" +"%b %d")
```

Read more on [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution)

Comment: i initialised it with the one u wrote-- var=$(date -d"-1day" +"%b %d") ...it didnt work...

Comment: how did you do it? on what system? are you using bash? when i copy paste this exact line it works. How do you check var? when using a variable you have to call it as $var.

Comment: i am using putty, yes using bash. i knw we use $var. it displays the error message-> date --d : illegal operation

Comment: its not working(either option) . it says date --d : illegal option

Comment: It should be a single dash before the d. Works for me (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
YESTERDAY=$(date -d yesterday '+%m/%d/%Y')
```

But this only works for GNU date. Please address the comments on your question, your answer depends on your version of UNIX and the tools.